# Group (or encapsulate) selective properties of Entity (spring jpa) into Json child object under parent

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson

Have entity (say) Car. Storing this entity in a **single** table in database.

```
@Entity
public class Car{
     @Id
     int id;
     String name;
     String type;
      
     //location
     String city;
     String State;
     String zip;
}
```

---

But have to **Return** all properties of entity to rest API GET all, but in below format (location properties wrapped under Location)

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"honda",
    .....

    "location":{
         "city":"Memphis",
         "state":"FL",
         "zip":"09089"
     }
     ..... 
}
```

---

This is a spring boot application using Spring JPA. Looking for a simple solution , where this can be achieved via annotation , as it is just a view to user (like @JsonView)?

Comment: find one straight forward solution to basically 1). Create a POJO Location with properties same as the ones in entity (for location). 2).  Use the POJO inside entity (composition) and override getter to return an instance of POJO created out of properties in entity 3). Mark the composite Location as Transient 4) @JsonIgnore the properties of entity (to avoid it being exposed)..   Trying to explore if there are any alternatives